# Determining the unique(?) set of euler angles that produce a set of 3 left hand orthonormal vectors in $R^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vectors, coordinate-systems

Given three vectors representing an x direction, y direction, and z direction, is there a way to uniquely determine 3 angular rotations around each of the x,y,z axes. I have no experience with differential geometry. I'm just trying to convert a "frame" I have of an object in 3-dimensional space to a set of rotations I can use to rotate a 3D model into it's proper orientation. It's for making a thing walk on the surface of a sphere and this is the only thing I have left to do. Otherwise, I'd be left with a very bizarre looking thing (it would appear to roll on the surface of the sphere).

Once again, reiterating:

> is there any way to take 3 vectors and determine rotations that produce them assuming we know which axis each one began as pointing in. Assume they are in regular cartesian coordinates (where x points out, y points right, and z points up).

Comment: To send the frame $\langle v_1,v_2,v_3\rangle$ to the coordinate frame $\langle e_1,e_2,e_3\rangle$ using only coordinate axis rotations, it might be easier to use three rotations around only *two* coordinate axes. First, apply a rotation $R_1$ around the $x$-axis to get $v_1$ into the $xz$-plane, then apply a rotation $R_2$ around the $y$-axis to get $R_1v_1$ to $e_1$, then apply a rotation $R_3$ around the $x$-axis again to get $R_2R_1v_2$ to $e_2$ and $R_2R_1v_3$ to $e_3$. Will have to consider the case when $v_1$ is on the $x$-axis separately.

Comment: It seems really restrictive to only be allowed to perform rotations around axes though. If you could apply arbitrary linear transformations (via matrices) to coordinate vectors, then to move the coordinate frame $\langle e_1,e_2,e_3\rangle$ to any new frame $\langle v_1,v_2,v_3\rangle$, you would just let $R$ be the matrix whose three columns are $v_1,v_2,v_3$. Is this not something you can do?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Why not use [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) to rotate it, instead?  Then you avoid possible Gimbal lock.

Comment: Then there's no time like the present to [learn](http://mathinfo.univ-reims.fr/IMG/pdf/Rotating_Objects_Using_Quaternions.pdf). ;-)

Comment: @TheGreatDuck If you have to use Euler angles then oh well.  I don't actually know much about Euler angles as I always use something that is [essentially equivalent to quaternions](http://www.geometricalgebra.net/quaternions.html).  Good luck.

Comment: Rotation is usually done BY multiplying "real-numbers" with quaternions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **unique** way. Say you have a model plane, pointing in the $x$ direction, $y$ direction is horizontal, perpendicular to $x$, and $z$ is vertical. Now you want to flip the plane upside down, pointing forward. That means $x'=x$, $y'=-y$, and $z'=-z$. I can get to this state in at least two different way. The most obvious one is a rotation around $x$ axis by 180$^\circ$. I can also rotate 180$^\circ$ around $y$ axis (plane is upside down, but pointing backwards in the $-x$ direction), and then rotate 180$^\circ$ around the $z$ axis.

In computer graphics programs what people are usually doing is deciding a simple rotation (usually the least amount of rotation) and decompose the path into equally spaced rotation angles, to make the motion seem smooth.

Comment: It looks like someone was unhappy about my answer, without saying why. @TheGreatDuck A way to get the rotation matrix is to write the new coordinate system $x',y',z'$ in terms of $xyz$ and assume that there is a matrix transformation between the two. Say the rotation matrix is R. Then $x'=R (1,0,0)$, $y'=R(0,1,0)$ and same for $z'$. We can write the three $x,y,z$ vectors as the identity matrix, so R is just the matrix made out of $x'y'z'$ vectors. Once you have R, you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Conversion_from_and_to_axis-angle

Comment: Even if I ignore the title, from your question "is there a way to ***uniquely*** determine 3 angular rotations around each of the x,y,z axes." I assumed that the uniqueness is important. If not, don't put it in the question